# Connect SAS to a Microsoft SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas

I'd like to connect SAS to a Microsoft SQL Server database but I didn't succeed.

I already have a database connection using a NT authentication.

For instance, when I want to connect R (the statistical sofware) to the db, I do that

> ch_db <- odbcConnect("sql_nt")

But when I do that in SAS, it doesn't work :

> LIBNAME sql ODBC DSN=’sql_nt’;

I have this error message :

> ERROR: Libname SQL is not assigned. ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME
>   statement. ERROR 22-7: Invalid option name SQL_NT.

I probably do a stupid mistake, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 3):

In SAS to make a ODBC CONNECTION TO SQL SERVER;
    First make a ***User DSN*** using *Windows ODBC Data Source Administrator*.  I use the SQL Server Native Client and the defaults.

THEN IN SAS EXECUTE THE FOLLOWING STATEMENT

```
libname mySasLib odbc datasrc='myUserDSN';
```

ALTERNATIVELY, from the SAS Explorer window GUI, choose **New** to invoke the New Library Dialog.

Note the DSN sources on your machine will be listed in the **Data Source** dropdown.

User ID, Password, and Options fields are optional and are left blank for Windows Integrated Security.

[image: New Library dialog];

SUBSEQUENTLY--to get the power of SQL pass-through--here is the syntax for creating a virtual view in Work; this is an incredible performance boost for my situation.

```
proc sql;
connect to ODBC as mycon (datasrc='myUserDSN');
create view one as
select colA, colB from connection to mycon
(select colA, colB from tableInDataSrc order by colA);
disconnect from mycon;
quit;
```

Then something like:

```
proc univariate data=one;
by colA;
histogram colB;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this page:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001355231.htm

Specifically, I think you should try it this way:

```
libname mydblib odbc user=testuser password=testpass datasrc=mydatasource;
```

Typically you should provide user name and password when connecting to a SQL server.  I assume you've verified that the ODBC connection was set up correctly (such as testing it with R).

Edit from comments:
If you're using NT authentication, then follow the instructions here: (from http://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/ts802.pdf )

```
libname odbclib odbc noprompt="dsn=sql_NT;Trusted_Connection=yes" 
schema=DBO;
```

I suspect the old style of just dsn="stuff" doesn't work on newer versions - though I only use OLEDB so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I'm using a a NT authentication, so I don't have to use 'user' and 'password'.

About the ODBC connection, It works with R, so I think it was set up correctly

Comment: Edited to include NT authentication, hopefully.

Comment: If using Windows Integrated Security (a.k.a. NT authentication) just omit the *user* and *password* options from the first libname statement in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to connect using both proc sql statements and the libname format. The latter seems more user friendly, here is one example:

```
  LIBNAME testLib ODBC DSN='sqlserver' user=userID pw=xxxxxxxx schema=dbo;
  title 'Testing Libname Option';
  proc contents data= testLib.mytable;
  proc print data=testLib.mytable(obs=10);
```

UserID and PWD need to come from your ODBC connection setup.

Answer (score 0):

I am a SAS newbie and  wasted quite a lot of time trying to create a 'user DSN' .
Thankfully,  I checked with admin team in my company.
 One of the SAS admin replied
"DSNs are configured on SAS server side "
She requested for 'MSSQL database and SAS server name' and created DSN for me.

Once connection was established i used below query

(P.S : I used windows authentication)

---

```
LIBNAME sql odbc = 'xxxxxx' ;
LIBNAME myfolder 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' ;

    proc sql;
        create table sql.target_table as select * from myfolder.mydata ;
    quit;
```

---