# Connecting SAS to SQL Server Database ODBC with Microsoft NT authentication with SAS on remote server

Tags: sql-server, sas, odbc

I'm trying to connect SAS to a SQL Server Database like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697362/connect-sas-to-a-microsoft-sql-server-database)
or [this guide](https://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/accessing-microsoft-sql-server-from-sas.pdf)

I went through the set up of the Microsoft ODBC Data Sources DSN and am able to connect to my database through the SAS Enterprise Guide GUI with the following steps:

[image]

Clicking on ODBC

[image]

And then clicking on Machine Data Source and selecting the database I set up with windows from the list.

However, I get a performance warning when connecting in this way, and I'd like to have a pure code soluion anyway.  When I try to connect to the same data source using something like:

```
libname mySasLib odbc datasrc='myUserDSN';
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: CLI error trying to establish connection: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver 
       specified
```

or when I try a SQL pass through:

```
proc sql;
connect to ODBC as mycon (datasrc='myUserDSN');
create view one as
select colA, colB from connection to mycon
(select colA, colB from tableInDataSrc order by colA);
disconnect from mycon;
quit;
```

I get a similar error:

```
ERROR: A Connection to the DATABASENAME DBMS is not currently supported, or is not installed at your site.
```

I am using SAS through a server, SAS is not installed on my local machine.  My hunch is that I need to do the Microsoft ODBC Data Sources set up on the server to set up the DSN there.  Is this correct?  It seemed odd to me that I could connect to the data source through the Enterprise Guide GUI though, does that make a different type of connection that doesn't need to be set up on the SAS server?

It may be difficult to do the required set up on the SAS server, are there other options for connecting?

Comment: EG has two modes, one runs locally and one runs on the server. My guess is that when it works in EG you're only working locally. Have you asked your IT team for the string to connect?

Answer (score 1):

If SAS is installed on the server, that is where the data access layer resides. See if you can connect using a simple SAS program via EG:

libname AUDIT ODBC NOPROMPT="server=SERVER01;driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;uid=UID;pwd=****;Database=SASAR;" STRINGDATES=NO IGNORE_READ_ONLY_COLUMNS=YES SCHEMA=DBO;

Fix the ODBC driver so it matches what is on the server

Comment: Thanks Alan! I get the same error as above, "ERROR: CLI error trying to establish connection: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver 
       specified"

Comment: Part of the problem is I'm not sure what to put in the server, I have the server address, I also have the Datasource Name I gave the data source when setting it up in Windows.  When I make the connection through the GUI I can get the connection string, which uses the DSN option instead of the server option.

Comment: By server address, is that the database server IP? If so, use it where you see server above (ex server=27.42.35.78). Leave driver off, if needed, and try that. Best place to see sample connection strings is: https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Steve, I am going to give you a bizarre, but very useful trick, to find the connection string. Use the technique described here: https://markdicken.wordpress.com/2019/01/04/udl-trick-comparing-azure-connection-string-to-normal-ms-sql-server-connection-string/. This is how I figure out a connection string.